# Low quality post upvotes

Tags: discussion

I have been seeing A user in particular post questions that in my opinion show 0 effort in research and no attempt to try and resolve on their own. My first instinct is to leave a comment and downvote the question, however, immediately after posting the question, it is upvoted after I downvoted.

Curiously, the same user posted their own answer and it was upvoted almost at the same instant (the answer was/is not even the answer).

link to the latest question(s):

[Q1](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/181153/error-formula-result-is-data-type-date-incompatible-with-expected-data-type#181157)

[Q2](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/181134/create-a-process-to-replace-two-workflow-rules)

how are these situations handled since I believe Voting is anonymous, right?

Comment: It really looks like the user have multiple accounts. I think this is supposed to be detected automatically. But I think it takes some time.

Comment: It's often a red flag that gets me investigating dupes, but very hard to catch them all and always helpful to get tips from the rest of the community.

Comment: @AdrianLarson [Here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/184088/after-delete-page-redirection-trigger-not-working) is another example of inappropriate upvotes

Comment: Not a ton of evidence for me to work with on that one @Rahul. It looks likely they have a couple co-workers voting for them but hard to say.

Comment: ok thanks for your opinion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This issue has been resolved. I had already noticed suspicious behavior and cleared it up once. This user has been notified again, more strongly this time.